# Find limit of a sequence: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-2)^n $ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {-2}{3})^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

my question is why the limit of this sequence: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-2)^n $ does not exist but the limit of this sequence: $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {-2}{3})^n $ is $0$ ? 
 Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \to K$ is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $n > N$, $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

That is clearly not true for $a_n = (-2)^n$ and any possible real number $K$. If $n$ is odd and large then $(-2)^n$ is a big negative number and $(-2)^{n+1}$ is a big positive number and there is no real number $K$ they can *both* be close to.

But this is true for $a_n = (\frac {-2}{3})^n$.  The larger $n$ get then $(\frac {-2}{3})^n$ get close to $0$.  It's true that if $n$ is odd then $(\frac {-2}{3})^n$ is negative and $(\frac {-2}{3})^{n+1}$ is positive but they are *little* negative and positive numbers so the can both be very close to $0$.

....

More formally.

If $1 > \epsilon > 0$ then and $K \ge 0$ then for any $N$ if $n$ is odd and $n > N$ and $n \ge 1$ then $|(-2)^n - K|= 2^n + K > 2^n > 2 > \epsilon$. so $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-2)^n \ne K$.

If $K < 0$ and then for any $N$ and if $n$ is even and $n > N$ and $n \ge 1$ then $|(-2)^n - K| = 2^n + |K| > 2^n > 2 > \epsilon$. so $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-2)^n \ne K$.

But for any $\epsilon > 0$ if $N = \log_{\frac 23} \epsilon$ then if $n > n$ then $|(\frac {-2}3)^n - 0| = (\frac 23)^n < (\frac 23)^N = \epsilon$.

So $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {-2}3^2 = 0$.

.....

We can take it a step further.  $\lim a^n$ will not exist if $|a| > 1$.  (because for large $n$ we can make $|a^n|$ become arbitrarily large so there is no number that it "gets close to").  If $|a| < 1$ then the limit is $0$ because for any value of $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $N$ where all $n > N$ are $|a^n| < \epsilon$.  And if $a = 1$ then limit is $1$ because $1^n = 1$... always.  And if $a = -1$ there is no limit because $(-1)^n$ bounces bace and forth between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 5):

It is because a sequence of the form $a_n=q^n$ converges only if $|q|<1$ or $q=1$.

Comment: It also converges if $q=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Because it's changing if $n$ is even or odd and have not the same result. Hence, the first limit does not exist. For the second limit, as the absolute value of $\frac{-2}{3}$ is less than $1$ power of it to the infinity goes to the $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-2)^n $ let consider what happens for $n$ even and for $n$ odd.

For $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac {-2}{3}\right)^n $ let apply ratio test on $\left|\left(\frac {-2}{3}\right)^n\right|=\left(\frac {2}{3}\right)^n$.

Comment: Really? You're going to use the convergence of a geometric series to conclude that the *sequence* goes to zero? The argument is completely circular. (-1)

Comment: @T.Bongers Many good answers have been already given, here I was interested to give some with series.

Comment: Funny, because I've seen you give this exact same answer before too. Perhaps time would be better spent on finding an appropriate duplicate, rather than posting an answer as fast as humanly possible.

Comment: @T.Bongers Anyway I agree the argument is quite circular!

Comment: @T.Bongers the part with the series was added after, I'll delete that, you are right it is not a good hint.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks for your suggestion.